# Getting a route to an external laravel instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have two separate Laravel instances/sites running on a server and want to be able to generate a url to a named route on one from code within the other.

For example the following named route exists in the first instance:
`Route::get('users/my_account', array('uses' => 'UsersController@myAccount', 'as' => 'my_account'))`

In the second instance I want to generate a url to the route above. Can anyone think of a clean way to do this, without explicitly knowing the url (i.e. only knowing the name of the route 'my_account')?

Basically I want to expose the RouteCollection of one site to the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty interesting question. There's no natively supported way of doing that and, from what I know, it won't ever.

You could try loading the routes file of the first application, parsing it's configurations (you will need that for reverse routing), construct a `Router` instance and use it, but I'm sure it won't be simple at all.

If you have a really, I mean **really**, good reason to use reverse routes, you can try building a small API on the first application. That API should receive the parameters necessary, those used in `url($params)`, and return the full url (with domain and everything). Although, this will introduce some serious performance issues.

IMHO, stick to hard coded `my_account`, leave a comment on the first application route and/or controller explaining that it's used on another project and move on :)

Comment: I believe this is the way to go. All foreign URLs should be handled as something completely decoupled from the core. The same we do with URLs that redirect to other website. I think the OP should handle the other app as another website.

Comment: Thanks. We've decided as you suggested to hardcode the routes. I like the idea of the API but in our instance the extra effort was not really worth what is a small gain. For interest's sake you can create an API endpoint that exposes the laravel instance's `RouteCollection`, and use that to build up an external router in the other instance. It turned out to be a little more effort than it was worth.

Answer (score 0):

I may call this a dirty trick. Supposing you have the following structure in your file system, where both paths are Laravel apps:

```
/path/to/apps/app1
/path/to/apps/app2
```

And you want to load the *routes* file from app1 into app2. You can do it as follow:

```php
include "../app1/apps/routes.php";
$url = URL::route('register');
```

Voilà! **But**, although it worked for me there are some points to consider.

- Include that file, will *surely* overwrites your current route collection for that process.
- If that last is true, then you can have problem generating other URLs, maybe in your views.
- The domain name will be of the current Laravel instance. It means that your URLs generated into app2 will hold the domain name of app1. I believe this is not what you want. But you can always generate non-absolute URLs with `URL::route('register', null, false)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try this approach, the problem as you mention is that your routes will get overwritten. Even if you then reparse the original routes file afterwards you could possibly be left with routes from the other instance which will now be accepted as valid even though they don't exsist.